# replying to a tweet in tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

There's an issue with my code where no matter what I try, every time I reply to a tweet, it just posts as a regular status update on my timeline.

here is a snippet of the code

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
 def on_status(self, status):
    tweetid = status.id
    tweetnouser = status.text.replace("@CarlWheezerBot", "")
    username = '@'+status.user.screen_name


    user_tweet = gTTS(text=tweetnouser, lang='en', slow=False)

    # Saving the converted audio

    user_tweet.save("useraudio/text2speech.mp3")

    # importing the audio and getting the audio all mashed up
    text2speech = AudioFileClip("useraudio/text2speech.mp3")
    videoclip = VideoFileClip("original_video/original_cut.mp4")
    editedAudio = videoclip.audio

    # splicing the original audio with the text2speech
    compiledAudio = CompositeAudioClip([editedAudio.set_duration(3.8), text2speech.set_start(3.8)])
    videoclip.audio = compiledAudio

    # saving the completed video fie
    videoclip.write_videofile("user_video/edited.mp4", audio_codec='aac')

    upload_result = api.media_upload("user_video/edited.mp4")
    api.update_status( status='@CarlWheezerBot',in_reply_to_status_id=[tweetid], media_ids=[upload_result.media_id_string], auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
```

I have also tried it without any status, as well as using status.id_str. Nothing seems to work., I have done it without the metadata parameter as well. I am following the documentation word for word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKAY. for everyone reading this in the future

use this `in_reply_to_status_id=tweetid`

do not use the square brackets. Everything works perfectly now

Comment: _"square brackets"_ would indicate an array with one element `[tweetid]`. tweetid is in fact an integer

Answer (score 0):

While playing around with it, I also noticed that you should also mention author of the tweet you're replying to, especially if you're replying to an existing reply because it will still post it as status update. Line from documentation:

> in_reply_to_status_id – The ID of an existing status that the update is in reply to. Note: This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the Tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include @username, where username is the author of the referenced Tweet, within the update.